# Is my application architecture still SOA?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, architecture, soa, inertiajs

I'm using Laravel for the backend, Vue.js for the frontend and Inertia.js to build my application. Since Inertia.js makes it so that without having to manually create an API or anything, you can easily get data from models and controllers into views, I was wondering if the architecture of my application is SOA (Service Oriented Architecture).

Ps: I used APIs too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's still SOA, since you still have APIs in your application.

Refer to this link to learn more about SOA:

https://www.ibm.com/cloud/learn/soa